# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list . ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Aqui les dejo el codigo**

```
import numpy
from pandas import DataFrame, Series


countries = ['Russian Fed', 'Norway', 'Canada', 'United States',
                 'Netherlands', 'Germany', 'Switzerland', 'Belarus',
                 'Austria', 'France', 'Poland', 'China', 'Korea', 
                 'Sweden', 'Czech Republic', 'Slovenia', 'Japan',
                 'Finland', 'Great Britain', 'Ukraine', 'Slovakia',
                 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Australia', 'Croatia', 'Kazakhstan']

gold = [13, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
silver = [11, 5, 10, 7, 7, 6, 3, 0, 8, 4, 1, 4, 3, 7, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
bronze = [9, 10, 5, 12, 9, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 6, 2, 1, 0, 1]

olympic_medal_counts = {'country_name': Series(countries),
                            'gold': Series(gold),
                            'silver': Series(silver),
                            'bronze': Series(bronze)}    
df = DataFrame(olympic_medal_counts)



df[['gold']['silver']['bronze']].apply(numpy.mean)

print (df)
```

**Este es el error que me manda**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-949694c8056a> in <module>()
     22 
     23 
---> 24 df[[gold][silver][bronze]].apply(numpy.mean)
     25 print (df)
     26 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? Para seleccionar tres columnas sería `df[['gold', 'silver', 'bronze']]` pero no tengo claro que es lo que pretendes obtener.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, lo que trato de conseguir es la media de esas tres columnas con el metodo ".apply(numpy.mean)". pero me sigue apareciendo el error de que deben ser integers no listas.

Comment: Si es la media de cada columna por separado no necesitas `apply`, `medias = df[['gold','silver','bronze']].mean()` /  `print(medias)`